# Jackson deserialize generic class, custom optional

Tags: java, jackson, unmarshalling

I have a type called `OptionalField<T>` which can be either empty(), `defined(value)` (like a normal optional) or `nullValue(default)` (represent a default value in JSON that could be anything like "n/a" or such).

My problem is with Jackson, because I need to create a custom serializer, and deserialiser capable of identifying the generic type and finding the appropriate default serializer, deserializer. I had not much trouble creating the serializer with a Contextual interface since it provides a property and `Serializer provider`

```
public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider prov, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
    ...
    JsonSerializer<Object> serialiser = prov.findValueSerializer(property.getType().containedType(0).getRawClass(), property);
    ...
}
```

But the deserializer is something else, I cannot find a way to identify the type and and find the default deserializer. Do you know how I could do that ? I read some things about BeanDeserializers but I don't think it answers to my problem.

**Update**

I went through the library https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8 to understand how they do it and it seems very low level manipulation (types and scala). Is there really no other way to do that ? Some higher way to use Jackson ? It really seems like a common use case to me (generic classes I mean) ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the type parameters in a serializer/deserializer isn't all *that* common, in my experience. It's more complicated than it could be, due in part to how type parameters were patched on to Java from version 1.5. This makes it difficult to get right in anything but the simple cases. Even the serializer example you give looks like it would only work for unparameterised classes, since it's finding a serializer based only on the raw T (what if you had `OptionalField<Set<SomeObject>>` ?)

The jdk8 or guava datatype add-ons are the place to start. Yes, they may seem daunting, but that complexity is (mostly) there for a reason. I've adapted them to support serializing/deserializing some other `Optional`-like type myself (`fj.Option`), so it's certainly possible.

When you implement `Deserializers`, the `findBeanDeserializer` method is called with the context of where the property was defined- so here you should have the full type with all its parameters:

```
    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> findBeanDeserializer(JavaType type, DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc)
            throws JsonMappingException {
        Class<?> raw = type.getRawClass();
        if (raw == Option.class) {
            JavaType[] types = config.getTypeFactory().findTypeParameters(type, Option.class);
            JavaType refType = (types == null) ? TypeFactory.unknownType() : types[0];
            JsonDeserializer<?> valueDeser = type.getValueHandler();
            TypeDeserializer typeDeser = type.getTypeHandler();
            // [Issue#42]: Polymorphic types need type deserializer                                                                     
            if (typeDeser == null) {
                typeDeser = config.findTypeDeserializer(refType);
            }
            return new FJOptionDeserializer(type, refType, typeDeser, valueDeser);
        }
        return super.findBeanDeserializer(type, config, beanDesc);
    }
}
```

Here `refType` is the type of the parameter to `Option`, so we pass it to the constructor of the deserializer- i.e. each occurrence of an `Option` in classes analyzed by Jackson will get its own deserializer instance, customised with the parameters of the `OptionalField` type.

By and large, I copied the `Optional` implementation and it worked quite easily. The implementation of the `OptionalDeserializer` et al isn't the clearest (as it combines two cases in one class, imho confusingly).